# How to calculate P-value by using Fisher's exact test in SAS

Tags: sas, statistics

how to calculate P-value by using proc freq ( by fisher exact method) in SAS, as i am getting a warning note while using chisq method in proc freq.
WARNING: 25% of the cells have expected counts less than 5. Chi-Square may not be a valid test
please provide me syntax and explanation why i am geting this warning?
thanks

Current Code:

```
ods OUTPUT Freq.Table1.ChiSq=P1_&TR1&V1(WHERE=(Statistic="Chi-Square") RENAME=(Prob=COL&TR1)); 
PROC FREQ DATA=P&V1;
    TABLE TREATMENT*SSA/CHISQ ;
    WHERE TREATMENT IN (1 &TR1);
RUN; 
QUIT;
```

Comment: Please provide the code you are currently using and what you have tried so far.

Comment: @probackpacker : here is code: ods OUTPUT Freq.Table1.ChiSq=P1_&TR1&V1(WHERE=(Statistic="Chi-Square") RENAME=(Prob=COL&TR1)); PROC FREQ DATA=P&V1; TABLE TREATMENT*SSA/CHISQ ; WHERE TREATMENT IN (1 &TR1); RUN; QUIT; i have 7 treatment groups(&tr1 to 7) and one vehicle pooled, so i am comparing each group with pooled group , so there are macros in the code. i need fisher p-value to be outputed

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is put / FISHER instead of / CHISQ in your TABLES statement.
You'll need to change the ODS statement as well, the table name is 'FishersExact'

Comment: : Thanks for the solution why i am getting Warning during the chisq method , Also i am getting two p-values(right/left sided), using fisher exact which value should i count as P-value?

Comment: A chi-squared test is only valid if each cell contains a certain number of values, the generally accepted number is 5 which is what SAS uses.  Therefore an exact test is required, i.e. Fisher.  You should only get 2 values coming out of this, the test value (Table Probability (P)) and the p-value (Pr <= P), so it's the latter that you should be using.

Comment: Ignore my last comment regarding the p-value, I've realised from your comment that you are doing this against a 2x2 matrix, where a left sided and right sided value are returned.  Without going into detail, I suggest you read the SAS documentation for PROC FREQ, in particular the Fishers Exact Test section which explains all the results.

Comment: thanks for you comments. i sure get on this. can you please suggest me some documentation or papers regarding concept of P-value and its calculation crieterias. it would be of great help..!!